# Необходимо переменным рандомно присваивать значения из бд

Tags: java, android

```
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.pokemongo.pokemon.database/databases/";
public static final String DB_NAME = "coordinate";
private static final int SCHEMA = 1; // версия базы данных
```

Есть 2 поля:

```
  private double mMyLatitude = 0;
private double mMyLongitude = 0;
```

БД создал в sqllite database и положил в папку asset.
Получаю все записи в БД:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        sqlHelper.open();
       userCursor =
         sqlHelper.database.rawQuery("select * from " + DatabaseHelper.DB_NAME, null);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ошибка открытия БД", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

1)предполагаю,что нужно создать cursor1 в котором рандомно из поля latitude будет выбрано значение и присвоено mMyLatitude
2)так же нуcursor2 выбираем поле longitude и выводим второе значение в эту переменную mMyLongitude

Попытался сделать запрос для первого пункта:

```
 private void randomCoordinate() {
    Cursor c =  sqlHelper.database.query(DatabaseHelper.DB_NAME + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",
            new String[] { DatabaseHelper.LATITUDE }, null, null, null, null, null);


}
```

запрос дял пункта 2:

```
        Cursor cLongitude =  sqlHelper.database.query(DatabaseHelper.DB_NAME + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",
            new String[] { DatabaseHelper.LONGITUDE }, null, null, null, null, null);
```

в бд хранится координаты,которые я потом буду выводить на карту

Answer (score 1):

```
//создадим два ArrayList
ArrayList<Double> latitudesAr = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> longitudesAr = new ArrayList<Double>();

//заполняем их соответсвенно значениями double из БД
if(cLatitude != null)
        {
    while(cLatitude.moveToNext){     
     latitudesAr.add(cLatitude.getDouble(cLatitude.getColomnIndex(DatabaseHelper.LATITUDE)));
     }
    }
if(cLongitude != null)
        {
                while(cLongitude.moveToNext){
      longitudesAr.add(cLatitude.getDouble(cLatitude.getColomnIndex(DatabaseHelper.LONGITUDE)));
            }
        }
//получаем рандомно выбранные индексы
Random r = new Random();
int indexLatitude = r.nextInt(latitudesAr.size());
int indexLongitude = r.nextInt(longitudeaAr.size());
//присваиваем переменным
mMyLatitude = latitudesAr.get(indexLatitude);
mMyLingitude = longitudesAr.get(indexLongitude);
```

Comment: а вызывать данный метод  где будет правильно?